# passing form data to a rest web api using guzzle

Tags: laravel, rest, guzzle

I am consuming a rest api that takes two numbers and calculates one of this; product, sum, division or multiplication based on user selection. the api only accepts get as the request method. I would like to collect this data and pass it to the api to do calculation and return the result for displaying to the user.

am using laravel

my controller method responsible for this looks like this

```
public function getRemoteData(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $operation = $data['operation'];
    $num1 = $data['num1'];
    $num2 = $data['num2'];
    $client = new Client();

    $request = $client->get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/multiply/4/3");
    $response = $request->getBody()->getContents();

    return $response;
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/data', 'calculator@getRemoteData');
```

```
<form action="/data" method="get">
```

Comment: So what's the question actually?